# Linux: Should I use processes or threads in this case?

Tags: linux, multithreading, unix, process, pipe

linux system, two rs485 ports, ~50 devices attached on these 2 ports. 
~100 processes in the system from linux itself. 4 core arm.
in many sense it's like a linux desktop with our app running.
could get very busy, e.g. like the moment you open office in linux.

1. original design was like this, also tested well enough,
   The main app has 10 threads on its own. 
   For each rs485, main process spawns off a process to monitoring all 
   devices on this
   port. (Since this is serial bus, it's basically a for loop doing tx/rx to 
   each device 1 by 1. We don't have locks inside the two rs485 processes.)
   so total 3 processes.
   Each rs485 process doesn't talk with each other, they only talk with main
   process through named pipe.
2. now ppl asks me to change to use threads. So only 1 process, 12 threads.
   With that rs485 thread crashes without clue, no core file.
   Ppl looked at code again and again and still clueless.

They don't want to go back to process, since
1. 3 processes with same name is confusing.
2. we don't know how to attach gdb to the process to debug. If only 1 
process, it's easier.

If you guys can help me with these

Q1: i think we can change process name, right ?
    or create pid files for each process, i'm new to these.

Q2: if you have 3 processes with same name, how hard is it for debugging ?
    Especially i want to debug the child process,
    how to do this in gdb ?
    can i set breakpoint in the code saying this is child, after the fork() ?

what happens if i change the child process name just after the fork(), how can i debug the child ?

Q3: why a thread can die without core file, while main process/thread can 
always generate code file ?

Q4：what can you gain if you use threads instead of processes in this case ?
    (in my opinion, only gains trouble.)

Q5: named pipe through threads or processes, performance big difference ?

Many many thanks !

Comment: As an aside, those are two extraordinarily lame justifications for not wanting to use processes.

Comment: @Duck, not quite understand your comments, which are the 2 cases not wanting to use process pls ?

Comment: (1) same name is confusing; (2) don't know how to attach debugger.

Comment: @Duck, process name can be changed using prctl i believe, as to debugger, there's answer below how to do it.

Comment: @Duck, from my point of view, i need to see sth. efficient, and robust. If need to add protection in thread then it's not efficient comparing with process. My 2 cents.

Comment: I guess at this point I am just confused.  You were the one who said "they" (presumably your employer) didn't want to go back to multiple process because of those two reasons.  I noted that they were silly.  And now you are explaining to me the reasons why I thought they were silly to begin with?  Are we talking past one another?

Comment: @Duck, i might got confused as my English is limited. We don't need to comment on ppl's design decision here, :) All i care is what's the correct way to do it for this case, and i think i got enough points from you guys already. Thanks !

Comment: @Duck, just looked at the dictionary and now learn what "lame" means, :) In general my co-workers are good at multi-threading, at least better than me, but i was so confused by them this time. To me i really don't (can't) care what company wants to do, tried my best, that's it. Ppl told me sometimes you have to be politically correct.

Answer (score 0):

It is by far harder to develop multithreaded applications, probably it's to early for your team. Go back to a separate processes approach.

1) What?

2) attach gdb to a running process by pid

3)you can directly pass data between threads, shared memory

4)named pipes are slow in both cases, no need for them with threads

Comment: Named pipes are not particularly slow, though unnecessary with threads.

Comment: @Duck Consider model serialization / deserialization. It is slow method of interprocess communication. OS overhead is involved too.

Comment: They are kernel buffers with a file system entry and a kernel synchronization primitive protecting them.  There is some copying and system call overhead with the trade-off being that the synchronization is automatic and they are easier than managing (in this case) 4 separate shared memory areas.  So they are slower than shared memory but in most cases plenty fast enough with some convenience bonuses.  All I am saying is don't automatically write them off as slow because they really aren't.

Comment: I call things slow if they are slower then all applicable alternatives. I don't mean they are unusably slow. Moreover threading complications in this context won't allow OP to use any other communication channel, so speed is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

Q1 - process name is just the name for the executable.  You probably don't want to change it.  You could track the pid for each instance in your pid file though.

Q2 - having things in different processes should make debugging a bit easier as it reduces the potential interactions.  Note that is very much a subjective opinion.  Gdb can take a command line option for the pid to attach to.

Q3 - it would depend on why things are dying.  Seg faults and similar should cause both to terminate unless you are playing with signal handlers.

Q4 - threads tend to be more efficient when there is a lot of inter-activity communication or synchronization or a lot of creation/destruction going on.

Q5 - don't see why there would be any significant difference.  Some pieces of the picture will be faster in one case or the other but I expect the end result to be break even.

Edit:  As Basilevs advises - go back to processes.  They are easier to work with and you had them working before.

Comment: we do use signal, if that may cause thread to do, then i need to read more, thanks for the hint.

Comment: It would more be if your threads and/or processes are installing signal handlers that you might see differences.